# Could not unserialize data of sales_flat_quote_item_option.value with record id 78558 Magento 2.3.5 Data Migration issue

Tags: frontend, magento2.3.5, data-migration-tool

```
[2020-08-11 14:35:47][WARNING]: Could not unserialize data of sales_flat_quote_item_option.value with record id 78558
```

Answer (score 0):

```
     <?php 
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $serializerInterface = $objectManager- 
    >create('Magento\Framework\Serialize\SerializerInterface');
   // $value = $serializerInterface->unserialize($block->getQuickviewInit());
    ?>
    <?php 
     $qvInit = $serializerInterface->unserialize($block->getQuickviewInit());
    //$qvInit = unserialize($block->getQuickviewInit());
    ?>
```